# AsyncTask in Android won't quit

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask that loads some content and puts it on the screen. Here's the code:

```
private class ContentLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    private boolean running = false;

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
        running = true;
        while (running){
            try {
                publishProgress();
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d("ContentLoader", String.valueOf(e));
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progressParams){
        setContents();
    }

    public void exit(){
        Log.d("ContentLoader-exit before", String.valueOf(running));
        running = false;
        Log.d("ContentLoader-exit after", String.valueOf(running));
    }
}
```

The setContents()-method loads some text from an SQLite-database and sets it to TextViews, which all works fine until I try to exit the task. When I call the exit-method, both of the log-entries show the value "false" and the loop keeps going.

I call the task from the onCreate-method of my Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
ContentLoader contentLoader = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    contentLoader = new ContentLoader();
    contentLoader.execute();
}
```

I want it to quit at onBackPressed:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (contentLoader != null){
        contentLoader.exit();
    }
    finish();
```

So how can get this thing to quit? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: where do you set running = false? inside doInBackground ?

Comment: Inside the exit-method between the logging.

Comment: sry, what I meant was, you are not calling the exit method inside the  while (running), therefore async task will not exit

Comment: So I can't call the exit-method from the onBackPressed-method in the Activity? How can I set running to false from outside then?

Comment: just use yourTask.cancel(true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `cancel` method to cancel the `AsyncTask` and use the `isCancelled` method in the while loop condition.

Here's an example :

```
private class ContentLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
        running = true;
        while (!isCancelled()){
            try {
                publishProgress();
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d("ContentLoader", String.valueOf(e));
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progressParams){
        setContents();
    }

}
```

Then use `cancel` method to cancel the task

```
ContentLoader contentLoader = new ContentLoader();
contentLoader.execute();
contentLoader.cancel(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `contentLoader.cancel(boolean mayInteruptIfRunning)` where boolean mayInteruptIfRunning if true will interupt running thread else it will allow it to complete and then cancel it.

And you can check the status using `contentLoader.isCancelled()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `cancel` mathod:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (contentLoader != null){
        contentLoader.cancel();
    }
    finish();
```

If your AsyncTask has a loop do:

```
@Override
Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    for(;;)
        if(isCancelled())
            return null;
}
```

If you're using something like a `URLConnection`, do this

```
@Override
Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    URLConnetcion uc = new URLConnection(new URL());

    if(isCancelled())
        return null;
    else
        //your normal processing
        process();
}
```